# Setting Oracle Database v$session Properties in Keycloak Quarkus with JDBC-Thin Connection

Tags: oracle, jdbc, keycloak, quarkus

I'm having trouble setting Oracle v$session Properties for Keycloak with Quarkus.
For example, with a jdbc connection, you can do the following:

```java
Properties pro = new java.util.Properties();
pro.put("v$session.osuser", "MY_USER");         
pro.put("v$session.machine", "DEPLOY_123");         
pro.put("v$session.program", "P26D_s");

DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();
con = DriverManager.getConnection(Url, pro);
...
```

What did I try?
Adding a *quarkus.properties* file with the following content:

```
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.additional-jdbc-properties.connectionProperties="v$session.OSUSER=MY_USER"
```

to Keycloak */conf* directory, just to test one property.
If I add *quarkus.datasource.jdbc.additional-jdbc-properties.v$session.OSUSER=MY_USER*, keycloak tells me, that the DataSource does not have a setter for the Property. Thats right, considering the following class:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/xa/client/OracleXADataSource.html, hence the *connectionProperties*. But the docu does not tell me anything about v$session Properties. At least I know, he's trying to apply the properties.
I'm testing the following way:

- building docker image, with the *quarkus.properties* at /opt/keycloak/conf
- starting docker compose with oracle-xe image
- after startup, look at keycloak logs and query SYS.V_$SESSION table in Oracle DB, to see if OSUSER, PROGRAM or MACHINE was set.

Does someone have an idea?
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, quarkus.properties did it, make sure to write the properties in lowercase and separate the properties with a semicolon.
Copy the file to /opt/keycloak/conf.

```
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.additional-jdbc-properties.connectionProperties=v$session.osuser=MY_USER;v$session.machine=DEPLOY_123;v$session.program=P26D_s
```